# Using Google Drive API v3 to convert .docx or .doc file to google docs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I need to upload a .doc or .docx file to google drive using Google Drive API v3 then convert it also using Google Drive API v3 so that the content of the file will be readable and editable in my own web application (hosted in node.js). I have tried to do this using drive.files.copy, however, I kept on receiving the error: The API returned an error: Error: Conversion of the uploaded content to the requested output type is not supported. Can anyone help me in figuring out how to do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the code that I used for converting, however, it is not working:

```
                drive.files.list({
                    q: "mimeType = 'application/msword'"
                    pageSize: 100,
                    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                }, (err, res) => {
                    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                    const files = res.data.files;
                    if (files.length) {
                    console.log('Files:');
                    files.map((file) => {
                        let result = (file.name).substring(0, (file.name).indexOf('.'));
                        console.log(file);
                        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
                        drive.files.copy(
                            {
                            fileId: file.id,
                            requestBody: {
                                name: result,
                                mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
                            }
                            },
                            (err, res) => {
                                if (err) return console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
                                console.log(res.data);  
                            }
                        );
                    });
                    }else {
                    console.log('No files found.');
                    }
                });
```

Here is the code I used for uploading the file:

```
            const driveResponse = drive.files.create({
                requestBody: {
                    name: filename,
                    mimeType: mimetype
                },
                media: {
                    mimeType: mimetype,
                    body: Buffer.from(data).toString()
                }
            });
            driveResponse.then(data => {
                if(data.status == 200)
                    res.redirect('/notes');
                else
                    console.log("file not uploaded.");
            }).catch(err => { throw new Error(err) })
```

Comment: I think that the file of `application/msword` can be converted to `application/vnd.google-apps.document`. So can I ask you about the detailed information of the file when the error of `The API returned an error: Error: Conversion of the uploaded content to the requested output type is not supported` occurs?

Comment: @Tanaike Here is the exact content of the file that I uploaded:
Ahello
Bhello
Chello
Dec. 3, 2010

I checked the file uploaded to google drive and I cannot open it also in google drive
I edited the question to include the code that I used for uploading the file, is it possible that I there is a problem with the code I used in uploading the file causing the error to occur?

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you download the `application/msword` file and you cannot open it, it is considered that the file is invalid the file as `application/msword`. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike I tried checking for its mimeType by printing it out in console.log and it states that the mimeType (.doc file) is 'application/msword'. I tried uploading a .docx file yesterday with the mimeType 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' and when I try to convert it to google docs, the same error also  occurs.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I couldn't understand the answer of `If you download the application/msword file and you cannot open it, it is considered that the file is invalid the file as application/msword. How about this?`.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I apologize for the misunderstanding. Do you mean: If I download the file and I cannot open it, then it means that the file is invalid? 
If that is the question, I tried downloading it now and even though I was able to open it, it seems that the file is corrupted or encoded into another version because it is not readable. Sample lines from the downloaded file:

ï¿½ï¿½ à¡± ï¿½                >   ï¿½ï¿½                  /           1       ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½    .   ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿

Comment: Thank you for replying. Thank you for replying. In that case, it is considered that the file is invalid file as `application/msword`. So how about confirming the file or how about testing the valid `application/msword` file?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the advice. I tried uploading a 'application/msword' file again now and the same thing happens. The file that I uploaded is fully working before the upload. However, after uploading it to google drive using the code I posted above, the file got corrupted again. I'm thinnking if something was wrong with the code I used for uploading file, however, I was not able to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that you had added your script for uploading the file. For this script, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? When I tested the modified script, I confirmed that the valid file of `application/msword` can be uploaded. If that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I saw your script for uploading the file of `application/msword`, I noticed a modification point. So how about the following modification? In this case, it is required to convert to the stream type.

Also, I confirmed that when I tested `buffer.toString()` as the body of `media`, the uploaded file was an invalid file.

#### Modified script:

```js
const { Readable } = require("stream");
const stream = new Readable();
stream.push(Buffer.from(data));
stream.push(null);

const driveResponse = drive.files.create({
    requestBody: {
        name: filename,
    },
    media: {
        body: stream
    }
});
driveResponse.then(data => {
    if(data.status == 200)
        res.redirect('/notes');
    else
        console.log("file not uploaded.");
}).catch(err => { throw new Error(err) })
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your value of `Buffer.from(data)` is the valid value as `application/msword`. So if the value of `Buffer.from(data)` is invalid as `application/msword`, please check the data again.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I tried your modified solution and it perfectly solved my issue. Thank you so much for the help and time!

Comment: @Octopus Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.